# MANCOVA with categorical moderator - it is possible?

Tags: categorical-data, mancova

I have two continuous variables which are my DEPENDENT variables and two PREDICTORS which are continuous too, but I need to test with MANCOVA an interaction of a third variable (moderator), which is CATEGORICAL. Is it possible? How can i do that?

On the Internet, i found this information (http://www.statisticssolutions.com/one-way-mancova/):

"One or more covariates, also called confounding factors or concomitant variables.  These variables moderate the impact of the independent factor on the dependent variables.  The covariates need to be continuous-level variables (interval or ratio data)."

Anyone can help me? There is a way to perform this MANCOVA?